# Finite disjoint union of the proper differences of the compact set forms a ring

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, compactness

It would be great if someone can give a proof that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, the class of sets that are all sets which are the finite disjoint unions of the proper difference of the compact sets forms a ring.

EDIT
To clarify, the ring discussed here is the ring of sets defined as
sets that are closed under operations

1. difference (i.e., relative compliment)
2. union

that is,
if $A,B \in R$

1. $A-B \in R$
2. $A \cup B  \in R$

finite disjoint union of the Proper difference of the compact set means
$$\cup_n E_n$$
where each $E_n$ is disjoint sets ranging from n=1,...,N and
$$E_n=(A_n-B_n)$$
where it is assumed that $B_n \subset A_n$
$ A_n$ and $B_n\in C$
and $C$ is a class of compact sets in a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: A ring for which operations?

Comment: The operations are taking the difference of the sets, and unions of the sets.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets

Comment: What is the *proper* difference of two sets? I know about the difference and the symmetric difference of two sets, but not about the proper difference.

Comment: And which operation is addition, which multiplication? I voted to close your question because it lacks essential information.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. It's not the ring in the abstract algebra. It's a ring of a set as you can see from the link 
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets

Comment: In essence, what I want to prove is the any finite union/differences of the element of the class of sets (let's call it A) that is finite disjoint union of the proper difference (i.e., relative compliment) of the compact sets in the given topology in a locally compact space, is again an element of A.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal A$ be the family of subsets of $X$ which are the finite unions of  pairwise disjoint differences of  compact subsets of $X$. Let us check that $\mathcal A$ is a ring.

Let $E,F$ be any members of $\mathcal A$. There exist finite families $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{F_j\}_{j=1}^m$ of pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ such that for each $i$ and $j$ there exist compact subsets $A_i\supset B_i$ and $C_j\supset D_j$ such that $E_i=A_i-B_i$ and $F_j=C_j- D_j$.

We claim that $E-F\in\mathcal A$. Since $\mathcal A$ is closed with respect to unions of disjoint sets and $E-F$ is a union of a family $\{E_i – F\}$ of disjoint sets,  it suffices to show that $E_i –F\in\mathcal A$ for each $i$.
But $$E_i –F=E_i-(\bigcup_j C_j- D_j)=\bigcap_j (E_i-(C_j-D_j))= \bigcap_j (E_i\cap D_j)\cup (E_i-C_j).$$
The latter intersection is a finite union of disjoint sets which are intersections of the form $\bigcap_j G_j$, where each $G_j$ is either $E_i\cap D_j$ or $E_i-C_j$. That is there exists a subset $S$ of $\{1,\dots m\}$ such that
$$\bigcap_j G_j= E_j\cap \bigcap_{j\in S} D_j \cap \bigcap_{j\in \{1,\dots m\}-S} (E_i - C_j)=E_j\cap \bigcap_{j\in S} D_j \cap E_j - \bigcup_{j\in \{1,\dots m\}-S} C_j\in\mathcal A$$ (here, for the convenience, we assume that the intersection of an empty family equals $X$).

For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ put $G_{ij}=E_i\cap F_j=(A_i\cap C_j)-(B_i\cap D_j)\in\mathcal A$.
Then $E\cap F=\bigcup_{ij} G_{ij}$ and $$E\cup F=(E\setminus F)\cup (F\setminus E)\cup (E\cap F)= (E\setminus F)\cup (F\setminus E)\cup \bigcup_{ij} G_{ij}.$$ Since the sets $E_i-\bigcup_j F_j$, $F_j-\bigcup_i E_j$, and $G_{ij}$ are pairwise disjoint, we see that $E\cup F\in\mathcal A$.